# Search in Binary Tree (BT) Not BST

Tags: c, search, binary-tree

I am trying to do a search operation in BT. For example:

```
       3 (Root)
   5       1
 6   2    0  8
```

This is my BT and this is the code I have written for search.

```
Node* search(Node *root,int key)
{
    if(root)
    {
        if(root->key==key)
        {
            cout<<root->key<<endl;
            return root;
        }
        search(root->left,key);
        search(root->right,key);
    }
}
```

Its a pre-order traversal with the condition, that when I find my desired node, I should return it.
For example if I call search(root,2) the search should return a Node* pointer to the node containing the value 2.

I believe when my code returns after the condition is met, it only returns to the outer call n doesn't exit out completely. For example if A Calls B Calls C, n then there is a return in C, it returns the value to B rather than to the function that called A.

I am not able to get my head around how to solve this. I am still quite new to recursion, so having a hard time visualizing things.

Any help appreciated !

Comment: You have to `return search(root->left, key)` and `return search(root->right, key);`. In addition, you should call those functions if the previous operation (the search in the node itself and `search(root->left, key)`, respectively) did not find the value.

Comment: Don't refer to code placed somewhere else. Put the relevant sections of code in your question to get good response.

Comment: Hi @Mohit Jain, Thanks I ll remember that in my future requests.

Comment: The paramagnetic croissant.   I changed my code to this but its still throwing error. Can you show me a code snippet, that would be really helpful.<code> Node* search(Node *root,int key)
{
if(root)
{
 if(root->key==key)
        return root;
else
{
return search(root->left,key);
return search(root->right,key);
}
}
} </code>

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: you need a return value when do not find the requested value. `return NULL;` at the end of your function.

Issue 2: when you recurse, you are delegating the job of finding the result to another function call - and you then need to return that result if it finds it. So you should do something like:

```
Node* r = search(root->right, key);
if (r) return r;
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to format my code block, but its not working so pasting my code on paste bin. com {I am using 4 spaces in front of the code line, and 2 spaces in the end for line break <br/>} Not sure why the editor is not picking it up. So I changed my code to this http://pastebin.com/iDsG7yei and now when I have a search key in left subtree, it doesn't go to the NULL Condition and is able to search, but with the key on the right, it goes to return NULL and never goes to the right subtree.

Comment: Yes, you want to return the result of searching the left subtree only if it returns a result. If it returns NULL then it should continue and search the right subtree.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node* search(Node *root, int key){
    if(root){
        if(root->key == key){
            return root;
        }
        Node *ret;
        (ret = search(root->left, key)) || (ret = search(root->right, key));
        return ret;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This works awesome ! thanks again. I also figured out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add exit function after the condition is met,to reduce overhead of the program.Also add a condition for not found

```
if(root->key==key)
    {
        cout<<root->key<<endl;
        return root;
        exit(-1); 
    }
```